# Resizing embedded videos with php

Tags: php, video

Hello i am trying to develop a video gallery
However the problem is that i should limit their dimensions.
So if the site owner wants to add a video he should paste the embed code..

```
<object width="480" height="385"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/R6uJGqS-KQY?fs=1&amp;hl=el_GR"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/R6uJGqS-KQY?fs=1&amp;hl=el_GR" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="480" height="385"></embed></object>
```

I decided to go with embed because there are many video providers out there....
So which is the best method to resize it before storing it to the database?
IS there a css only solution?
Also i noticed that video.google uses only  and inline css for width height! That would overide any css setting...
So regexp is the only solution ?

Comment: Those are `tag attributes`, not `inline CSS`.

Comment: check embed code for video.google.com!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I had to do a similar task I would convert the html into xml and get the height/width.
After that I would resize the height or width (depending on what you need) keeping the aspect.
Doing this will not resize the actual video but it'll help you to resize it via HTML.

```
<?php

$string = <<<XML
<?xml version='1.0'?> 
<object width="480" height="385">
       <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/R6uJGqS-KQY?fs=1&amp;hl=el_GR"> </param>                    
       <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
       <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>
    <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/R6uJGqS-KQY?fs=1&amp;hl=el_GR" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true"     width="480" height="385"></embed>                
    </object>
XML;
$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);                                        
echo "Original Width/Height:".$xml->attributes()->width."px/".$xml->attributes()->height."px<br>";

$newwidth = 280;
$newheight = ($xml->attributes()->height / $xml->attributes()->width) * $newwidth;

echo "New Width/Height:".$newwidth."px/".$newheight."px<br>";

echo <<<HTML
    <object width="{$newwidth}" height="${newheight}">
    <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/R6uJGqS-KQY?fs=1&    amp;hl=el_GR"> </param>
        <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
        <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>
    <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/R6uJGqS-KQY?fs=1&amp;hl=el_GR" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true"     width="${newwidth}" height="${newheight}"></embed>
    </object>
HTML;
?>
```

I've tested this and you can see it in action at:
Demo: http://itnews-bg.com/test.php
Source: http://itnews-bg.com/test.phps

There may be other better ways but this is what I would do.
Hope it helps you :)

Answer (score 1):

That provides error when i have to use embed code of dailymotion video:

```
<object width="480" height="360">
  <param name="movie" value="http://www.dailymotion.com/swf/video/x9rswu?width=&theme=none&foreground=%23F7FFFD&highlight=%23FFC300&background=%23171D1B&start=&animatedTitle=&iframe=0&additionalInfos=0&autoPlay=0&hideInfos=0"></param>
  <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always"></param>
  <embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash" src="http://www.dailymotion.com/swf/video/x9rswu?width=&theme=none&foreground=%23F7FFFD&highlight=%23FFC300&background=%23171D1B&start=&animatedTitle=&iframe=0&additionalInfos=0&autoPlay=0&hideInfos=0" width="480" height="360" allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always"> </embed>
</object>
```