# wordpress video resizing

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, video

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Resizing embedded videos with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4132893/resizing-embedded-videos-with-php)

I would like to set the videos to height 280, width 520 on my wordpress homepage. The current code uses the original youtube height & width:

```
        <div class="entry">

            <?php the_content(''); ?>

        </div>
```

when I output the code, the video is still at 640x480. Any suggestions on how to resize? I have tried css with no luck.  this is for a custom wordpress theme we're working on.

thanks

Comment: You need to add the code that is actually embedding your video

Answer (score 0):

`<?php the_content();?>` is just pulling 'the content' from a page or post. In that page or post should be where you actually have the embed code and is where you can change the html height and width attributes.

Unless there is a plugin involved somewhere in which case it's probably somewhere in the plugins code. But I don't think so since you are using 'the_content' to display it in the template.

Comment: Ian, thanks for response. Were looking through the 'templates editor' for the page. do you have a guess on what .php it might be in. example: index.php(main index), single.php(single post). ?

Comment: Could be single.php if it's for posts or page.php if it's for pages. If you have a child theme those files would override the ones in wordpress and be the ones to look at. But the code <?php the_content();?> is what you would find there. While the actual embed code would be seen in the post or page through the wp admin dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the [Youtube documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#Embedding_a_Player) if you want to get a better idea of how it works. You should be able to change the iframe size to whatever but after playing with it for a bit it looks like you will always be streaming a 320x240.